# Method calling within the same method

Tags: java, mysql

I am working on a small app that will allow a student to join a class when selected.  I want to have the user be able to select a student by ID, select a class by ID and have the user be added to that class.  This works, but after the student is added, I want the program to ask if the student wants to join another class, instead of resetting the whole program and having to go back.

I think I am close to a solution, but do not know how to get my method (signUp()) to go back to halfway through the method.  Does this make sense?  Once a student is entered in a class and "join another class" is selected  I want to return to the **bold** comment in the code.

Sorry if this is long-winded and confusing, I'm new to this, so I appreciate your patience!

```
static void signUp() {
        System.out.println("\nSign Up For a Class\n");
        try {
          Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter Student ID: ");
          String user_entered_student_id = input.nextLine();

          Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ClassSelector?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "", "");
          Statement myStmt = con.createStatement();
          Statement myStmt2 = con.createStatement();
          Statement myStmt3 = con.createStatement();

          ResultSet rs;
          rs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT student_name FROM ClassSelector.students WHERE student_id = " + user_entered_student_id);
          while (rs.next()) {
            String userEnterId = rs.getString("student_name");
            System.out.println("Is " + userEnterId + " the correct student? (Y/N)");
            String confirm = input.nextLine();

            if (confirm.equals("Y") || confirm.equals("y")) {
              ResultSet rs2 = myStmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes");
              while (rs2.next()) {
                String avlClasses = rs2.getString("class_id") + "\t" + rs2.getString("classname") + "\t" + rs2.getString("description");
                System.out.println(avlClasses);
              }
            } else if (confirm.equals("N") || confirm.equals("n")) {
              System.out.println("Oops, let start over");
              return;
            }
    **//RETURN TO THIS SECTION OF CODE AND PROCEEED**
            System.out.println("Enter Class ID from Classes Listed Above to Join: ");
            String selectedClass = input.nextLine();
            ResultSet rs3 = myStmt3.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ClassSelector.classes WHERE class_id = " + selectedClass);
            while (rs3.next()) {
              String innerJoin = (userEnterId + " has been added to " + rs3.getString("classname") + " " + rs3.getString("class_id"));
              System.out.println(innerJoin);
              String student_classJoin = "INSERT IGNORE INTO student_x_class" + "(student_id,student_name, class_id, classname)" + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
              PreparedStatement pStmt = con.prepareStatement(student_classJoin);
              pStmt.setString(1, user_entered_student_id);
              pStmt.setString(2, userEnterId);
              pStmt.setString(3, rs3.getString("class_id"));
              pStmt.setString(4, rs3.getString("classname"));
              pStmt.executeUpdate();
              System.out.println("Would you like to enroll " + userEnterId + " into another class? (Y/N)");
              String additionalClass = input.nextLine();
              if(additionalClass.equals("Y") || additionalClass.equals("y")){
                  signUp();
              }
            }
          }
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException SQL) {
          SQL.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception EXC) {
          EXC.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
```

Comment: Having multiple methods is possible, some might even call it an advantage.

Comment: just use a 'while' loop. Get a boolean, set it to false when you're happy,
Btw for checking if string equals small case letter or upper case letter, you can use convenience method called 'equalsignoreCase(...)' Also you should 'close()' 'Connection' and 'ResultSet' in a finally.

Comment: You nailed it. Your code is `long-winded and confusing` ... and that is precisely because you are doing everything within one method. Don't start with coding. Sit down, and think about the various things that need to happen. Then think how you could "group" things into reasonable units ... and then write methods that represent such units. You know - if your code has a clear structure ... you would not need to ask such a question, as the answer would be easy to find even for a newbie.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I'll think about it some more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is *very* confusing.  But let's take a step back and look at some *pseudo*-code which may represent the sort of structure you're looking for.

Let's start with the operation being performed.  Something like this:

```
studentID = prompt("enter a student ID");
student = get_from_data(studentID);
courseID = prompt("enter a course ID");
course = get_from_data(courseID);
insert_in_data(studentID, courseID);
```

The details are very implementation-specific, but in general your primary logical approach should semantically look very similar to that.  In fact, it's often a *very good idea* to extract code into small individual methods where the method name *describes* the operation being performed.  Then the overall sequence of steps reads like a short story which describes the business process.

Now, you want to *repeat* that structure?  Well, that's what loops are for.  Something like this:

```
while(!someTerminatingCondition) {
    // the steps above
}
```

Now we just need to define that condition.  It's based on user input, right?  So something like this:

```
shouldContinue = true;
while(shouldContinue) {
    // the steps above
    shouldContinue = prompt("continue?");
}
```

To give you something to Google, what you're describing is often called a "game loop".  The idea is that the entire process should repeat, over and over, until some specific condition is met.  (In a game this condition would be the determination of a winner.)

Comment: Hi David, this helps a lot! SO I should break down the code into much smaller methods within the signUp() method. Could you show me an example just for the studentId() so I can visualize it?  I really appreciate the help.  I feel like I'm starting to get it though!

Comment: Also, when I try to break these into separate methods, the variables are not recognized between methods.

Comment: @Rassisland: What you're asking at this point is pretty broad for Stack Overflow.  Any individual attempt and question thereof could make for a good separate question.  But "how do I organize my code" is very, very broad.  To which the only real answer is, "with experience".

Comment: I totally understand; I'll keep working on it.  Thanks for the help.